# Mysql Query looping through multiple variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to display a variety of results with a mysqli query and i feel like i am using up too much code. I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if i can loop through multiple variables.

For the example i have multiple Agents and Multiple columns for the agents wich are equal for all the agents. I want to run the query so it will cycle through all the columns for and agent then output the data and then move on to the next agent and do the same

```
echo "<table>
<tr><th>Van</th><th>Aantal</th></tr>";

$sql = ("SELECT SUM(Case_closed) as sum_closed FROM productie WHERE Agentnaam='Agent1' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ;
            $Case_closed = $result->fetch_object()->sum_closed;

echo "<tr><td>Cases closed</td>";
echo "<td>$Case_closed</td></tr>";

$sql = ("SELECT SUM(Case_handled) as sum_handled FROM productie WHERE Agentnaam='Agent1' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ;
        $Case_handled = $result->fetch_object()->sum_handled ;

echo "<tr><td>Cases handled</td>";
echo "<td>$Case_handled </td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: You can just `SELECT SUM(Case_closed) as sum_closed, SUM(Case_handled) as sum_handled FROM productie WHERE Agentnaam='Agent1'`...

Comment: Better still, `SELECT Agentnaam, SUM(Case_closed) as sum_closed, SUM(Case_handled) as sum_handled FORM productie GROUP BY Agentnaam`

Comment: I am not sure if that answered my question. I don't want to have a total of all the case_closed by all the agents. I want to output data in a table like: [ Agent1 - Case_closed :1 Case_handled:5 Case_forwarded: 22 Case_dismissed: 0 ] [  Agent2 - Case_closed :5 Case_handled:9 Case_forwarded: 1 Case_dismissed: 11]

Comment: Try the `group by` query. See what rows you get out of it. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: If i keep the rest of the query the same it results in 0 .

Comment: Ok i got it working for 1 agent and now i need to cycle through an array of agents until all the agents have been outputted `code     $s = "SELECT * FROM productie WHERE Agentnaam='Agent1'"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($connect,$s);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); Echo "<table><tr><th>Agent1</th><th>Ammount</th></tr>";
 
 Echo "<tr><td>Cases closed:</td><td> " .$row[2].    "</td></tr>";
 Echo "<tr><td>Cases handeled:</td><td> " .$row[3].    "</td></tr></table>";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109334/discussion-between-derik-and-niet-the-dark-absol).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with : Foreach

```
  $connect = new mysqli ('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
} else {

    $normal_array = array('Agent1','Agent2','Agent3');
    foreach($normal_array as $value){


    $s = "SELECT * FROM productie WHERE Agentname='$value' AND Date='$actual_time'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$s);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);



    Echo "</br></br><table><tr><th>$value</th><th>Ammount</th></tr>";

    Echo "<tr><td>Cases closed      :</td><td> " .$row[2].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>Cases handled     :</td><td> " .$row[3].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[4].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[5].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[6].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[7].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[8].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[9].       "</td></tr>";
    Echo "<tr><td>another column    :</td><td> " .$row[10].      "</td></tr></table></br>";
```